# Python - How to create a new dataframe for each month out of a list of data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of stock data over the years and I want to remove the bottom x% in terms of market cap in each month. My idea is to  make a loop that creates a new Pandas dataframe for each month, and then within that month, I remove the bottom x% in terms of market cap. This is what the data looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year-month'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))

df = df.sort_values(['year-month', 'MarketCap'], ascending=[True, False])

df = df.groupby('year-month').apply(lambda x: x[x['MarketCap'] > x['MarketCap'].quantile(.1)]).reset_index(1, drop = True)

df = df.drop(columns=['year-month']).reset_index().drop(columns=['year-month'])
```

First create a column contains only year and month.

Then sort `year-month` and `MarketCap` column ascending and descending.

Group by `MarketCap` column and filter out the row below 10% in each group.

Comment: hmmm I just ran the code, for some reason the amount of rows before and after is the same

Comment: Thanks! The new df now just has the index and the MarketCap; if you could make sure that the other columns are also there that would be great! I am thinking of using inner join to combine these 2 sets of dataframes but there has to be an easier method right?